# Print command is not printing values and there is no error given

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a simple program that detects outgoing connections by using the values given from the command "netstat-b". However, the results will not print and there is no error showing why. Help would be appreciated!

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
import ctypes, sys

#This runs the file as admin
def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False
#This should be printing the netstat b values, but it is not
if is_admin():
    a = os.popen('netstat -b').read()
    print("\n Connections ",a)
else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv[1:]), None, 1)
```

This code returns nothing. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: What is expected? Which part of the code should the flow go thru? What havev you debugged so far?

Comment: I am assuming that the `if` block should execute. If so, is the block being entered? Try adding a print statement there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the python documentation, `os.popen()` is deprecated.  You should use `subprocess` instead.  Like so:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.run('netstat -b').read()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html